# Temporary blocks in update command making DISK FULL redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am new to redshift and struggling to update a column in a redshift table. I have a huge data table and added an empty column to it. I am trying to fill this empty column by joining it with another table using the update command. What I am worried about is that even though there is 291 GB of space left, temporary blocks being created by this UPDATE statement produce the DISK FULL error. Any solutions or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to perform a large `UPDATE` command in Amazon Redshift tables.

The reason is that updating even just one column in a row causes the following:

- The existing row will be marked as *Deleted*, but still occupies disk space until the table is VACUUMed
- A new row is added to the end of the table storage, which is then out of sort order

If you are updating every row in the table, this means that **the storage required for the table is twice as much**, possibly more due to less-efficient compression. This is possibly what is consuming your disk space.

The suggested alternate method is to **select the joined data into a new table**. Yes, this will also require more disk space, but it will be more efficiently organized. You can then delete the original table and rename the new table to the old table name.

Some resources:

- [Updating and Inserting New Data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html)
- [How to Improve Amazon Redshift Upload Performance](https://www.flydata.com/blog/how-to-improve-amazon-redshift-upload-performance/)